# Is visualising centripetal acceleration, as pulling the rotating body towards the centre, correct?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, acceleration, centripetal-force

**Centripetal force** would literally mean *‘the centre-seeking force’*. So in order to bring a body towards the centre it *turns* it and the body is always trying to reach the centre however is unable to reach it and ends up rotating. Is this way of describing circular motion-rotation about a fixed axis correct? Also is it that a rotating body would feel an **inward pull towards the centre**? Why or why not?

*[Here: rotation could be like any of Earth’s two circular motions of rotation about its axis and revolution about Sun]*

Answer (score 0):

For a mass moving along a curve, there must be an applied force which is causing it to accelerate toward the center of curvature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was correct to visualise a centripetal force as one that pulls a moving body towards the centre of curvature of the body's path of motion.

In your second question you talk about a rotating body. Are you clear about the different between rotation and circular motion? A body in circular motion must experience a force directed towards the centre of the circle- if there is no component of force towards the centre, then the body will continue in a straight line tangentially.

Comment: What I mean wasn’t rotation but more like revolution in a circular (not elliptical) path.